# How to click something in the DOM with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have looked around for this but cant seem to get this working. How do I click something in the DOM with jQuery, not a user action, but JS action?

JS:

```
$('a#more').click();
```

HTML:

```
<a id="more" href="www.ksl.com">click</a>
```

See jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/qw7b2ou3/1/

Comment: You mean for jQuery to trigger the event itself?

Comment: Yes. So the user does not have to click it. The script does it

Comment: click() and trigger("click") are the same thing under the cover.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow the click, you have to call the DOM method, not the jQuery click method.

```
$('a#more')[0].click();
```

or

```
$('a#more').get(0).click();
```

The reason why `$('a#more').click();` or `$('a#more').trigger("click");` does not work is because it only triggers the event handlers attached, it does not actually click the link.

Comment: Ah I see where I was going wrong. I was not accessing the array and just doing $(selector).click(). I needed to access the first index of the array. Thanks!

Comment: no, that is not the case.... calling click() on jQuery only triggers the click events attached.

Comment: @iHelpYou What `[0]` does in this case is get the underlying DOM element. Using `element.click()` simulates a click on the element.

Answer (score 0):

See this JSFiddle to help you out. You will notice this code console logs your selector in an array:

```
var selectMe = $('a#more');
console.log(selectMe); //  [a#more, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "a#more"]
```

To get this selector element you are trying to click you need to access that index of the array.

```
selectMe[0].click();
```

Here is the fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/qw7b2ou3/2/